# Turn Server is not working in Firewall, NAT in CentOS

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn, rtcmulticonnection, rfc5766turnserver

I am facing issue on internal network, when I establish a call from internal network to public network, Peer gets disconnected. It is working internally in network and it is also working public to public network. But it is not working for internal to public network. I have already open required ports on turn/stun server machine. Is there anything I need to do with the firewall or NAT to solve the issue?

Comment: This one is a serious issue that is bothering many developers. One thing we as developer do not understand, that why Appear.in(which is also made in WebRTC) is not having firewall issue, and why we are facing this issue. What are we doing wrong?

Comment: Better post this question on https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/